# what is the possibalities of getting org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Character reference "&#28" is an invalid XML character.?

Tags: java, javascript, portal, websphere-portal

I need figure out that where exactly 
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Character reference "&#28" is an invalid XML character.

exception is throwing. from the logs implemented its showing there is no exception in fetching the data from the DB. its successfully fetching the data from the DB from this point i have stored fetched the data in the list and passing into the portal server. from portal server i am getting this error even though there is no exception from the process server

Answer (score 0):

XML spec says that all characters <32
are invalid except for tab / newline / carriage return[1].

> 

"and hash 28"  is the way character 28 displayed in html

or

you can just stick `<?xml version="1.1"?>` on the top of your files and you'll be in good shape. If you're dealing with streams, write a wrapper that rewrites or adds that processing instruction.

Answer (score 0):

Character reference must end with `;`, that is it should be `&#28;`